# GRE score submission

Tags: masters, graduate-admissions

I wish to apply for M.Sc studies in Computer Science to 3-4 universities. Only one of them requires the applicants to take a GRE (general test), and my question is as follows: is it a good idea to send the scores to the rest of the universities even though they do not specifically require it? Will it affect my chances?

FYI: I did one practice test and didn't get a good Quantitative Score (only 145), although I took the test without preparation, without paper (soon after taking the practice test I've read that is allowed scraps of paper) and after 4-5 years after finishing undergraduate studies.  I think with 2 months or so of moderate studies I can get about 160. What do you think I should do?

Answer (score 6):

A good GRE score *can* help your chances at admissions; a poor GRE score does not do anything to help your chances, but they can hurt you, particularly if you're already a somewhat "borderline" case.

However, if a school does not require GRE scores, then I would only submit them if they are strong (well above average). Otherwise, you're introducing at best a neutral "fact" into the conversation.

Answer (score 2):

My philosophy in application processes is what you present should only serve to strengthen your case: *"that you should be admitted/accepted to .... "*. If you look at it with this perspective, I would say submit only what's required of you and what you think gives a fair but good image of your intellectual/social abilities. Anything else has the potential of raising questions in the admission officer's head.

Overall I agree with @aeismail's answer. Submit scores/GPAs/transcripts only if you are confident in them.